# Unrecognized options when compiling PHP 8: --with-gd --enable-gd-native-ttf

Tags: php, linux, makefile

I am trying to use a GD function: `imagettfbbox()`, but it is undefined. I have compiled my own build of PHP with argon2 support since I am on Ubuntu 21.10.

I am configuring as such:

```
./configure --with-password-argon2 --with-jpeg --with-freetype --enable-bcmath --enable-calendar --enable-dba --enable-exif   --enable-ftp   --enable-mbstring   --enable-shmop   --enable-sigchild   --enable-soap   --enable-sockets   --enable-sysvmsg   --enable-gd-native-ttf    --with-gd   --with-curl   --with-gettext   --with-openssl   --with-pdo-mysql   --with-zlib
```

I have finally found all the ./configure options I need as stated above. However, `--with-gd` and `--enable-gd-native-ttf` are unrecognized and will not integrate with my build. **How do I access the aforementioned function?** I cannot find any recent information (in the last 10 years) on this subject, as it seems --with-gd might have been deprecated in php 7.2. I am building the latest version (PHP 8.2-dev). Thanks in advance

Comment: what OS ? Also why not just install the `php8.0-gd` extension, along with the php v8 from the repos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`--enable-gd-native-ttf` is deprecated as per the image documentation:

> To enable support for native TrueType string function add --enable-gd-native-ttf. (This option has no effect and has been removed as of PHP 7.2.0.)

Also `--with-gd` was replaced with `--enable-gd`.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php

Comment: SAVIOUR! Thank you for your time in helping me! I really could not find any answers elsewhere.

Comment: @MaysenCooper You are welcome. PHP gets a lot of hate online but its documentation is good and is enhanced by PHP developers comments and examples (scroll to the bottom of each page). All PHP functions have their documentation page.

Comment: I had looked at the linked page before and didn't see the hidden "As of PHP 7.4.0, --with-gd becomes --enable-gd". If anyone finds this question, here was my final configuration: `./configure --with-jpeg --with-freetype --enable-bcmath --enable-calendar --enable-dba --enable-exif --enable-ftp --enable-mbstring --enable-shmop --enable-sigchild --enable-soap --enable-sockets --enable-sysvmsg --enable-gd --with-curl --with-gettext --with-openssl --with-pdo-mysql --with-zlib --with-password-argon2`